# Public groovy method must be public, says the compiler

Tags: groovy, traits, spock, grails-3.3

What is the cause of this error, and how do I fix it?

At first glance, it seems like a defect in the groovy compiler.

```
:compileIntegrationTestGroovystartup failed:
C:\src\my-project\src\integration-test\groovy\my\project\MyServiceISpec.groovy: 31: The method setup should be public as it implements the corresponding method from interface my.project.MyTrait
. At [31:5]  @ line 31, column 5.
       public void setup() {
       ^

1 error
```

My grails integration test looks like this:

```
@Integration
@Rollback
class MyServiceISpec extends Specification implements MyTrait {
    @Autowired
    MyService service

    OtherService otherService = Mock()

    public void setup() {
        myTraithMethod()
        service.otherService = otherService
    }
}
```

My trait looks like this:

```
trait MyTrait {
    public void setup() {
        myTraithMethod()
    }

    private myTraitMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Update** Added `public` keyword to the trait setup method.

Comment: Grails version: 3.3.4, groovy version: 2.4.7, java 8, gradle 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the source of that problem is AST, because Spock uses AST transformations and compiles the specification. You can read here http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-traits.html#_compatibility_with_ast_transformations this:

> Traits are not officially compatible with AST transformations. Some of
>   them, like @CompileStatic will be applied on the trait itself (not on
>   implementing classes), while others will apply on both the
>   implementing class and the trait. There is absolutely no guarantee
>   that an AST transformation will run on a trait as it does on a regular
>   class, so use it at your own risk!

You can solve it by renaming `setup()` method in the trait on `traitSetup()` for example and calling it from the specification `setup()` method like this:

```
@Integration
@Rollback
class MyServiceISpec extends Specification implements MyTrait {
    @Autowired
    MyService service
    OtherService otherService = Mock()

    void setup() {
        service.otherService = otherService
        traitSetup()
    }

    def 'some test here'() {
        ...
    }
}

trait MyTrait {
    void traitSetup() {
        myTraitMethod()
    }

    private myTraitMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That is correct, you can't have Spocks special methods in traits.

Answer (score 0):

1/ Not sure, but the trait name is ResetsDatabase and your test implements MyTrait.
Possibly some mixup with traits ?
2/ It seems to me that you can't have a public method on the implemented method if your traits says the the method (setup here) is private.

Comment: Fixed #1 (this was an artifact of sanitizing my code for posting). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Added `public` keyword to the method declaration in the trait, but this didn't have any effect.